# Need help grabbing a corresponding set of data in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I'm working with a dataframe in python using pandas. I need to use the max.() method to find the largest number in a particular column and then find its corresponding name in another column. I then need to print out a sentence that shows the largest number in the column with the name associated to it. I cannot seem to figure out how to find the corresponding name in the second column after achieving the correct largest number. I believe it has something to do with the iloc or loc functions but i'm not entirely sure as I am still new to python. Thanks cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use iloc in this way to solve your problem :

```
df.loc[df["Num"] == max(df.Num)].color

df.loc[df["Num"] == max(df.Num)].color.values

df.loc[df["Num"] == max(df.Num)].color.values[0]
```

Here Num is column which contains number and color is the column from which you want to get value

[You can refer from here for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44dr9.png)

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew I was close it was just slipping my mind. Appreciate the detailed layout very much, cheers!